# how to open new windows, and refresh the web page long?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

how to open new windows, and refresh the web page long ?
if `st=1` then open new windows and refresh web page, when `st=2` then redirect ?

```
$.post(
    submit_url_pos,
    $('#form_pos').serialize(),
    function(response){ 
        var x= JSON.parse(response);
        if(x.st===1) {
            window.open(print_label+ '/' + x.data, 'print','height=400,width=300');
            window.location.href=return_url;
        }
        else if(x.st===2) {
            window.location.href=return_url;
        }
        else {
            console.log("ERROR: "+response);
        }                        
    }
);
```

Comment: now, what you face?

Comment: now only refresh and redirect, not open new windows. Right?

Comment: window.open not working

Comment: can you do the `console.log(print_label+ '/' + x.data)` and see what url is getting form

Comment: `window.open` not working but `window.location` is working. right?

Comment: right!window.open not working but window.location is working